# Can't call function in onTextChange reactnative

Tags: javascript, input, react-native, state

I made a search input and when search keyword changes to trigger the function `getSearchResult` to get a result array for a  to render, anyhow, here is my current implementment:

```
getSearchResult(text){
         var res = [];
         for(var i = 0;i<myData.length;i++){
             for(var j=0;j<myData[i].content.length;j++){
                 if(myData[i].content[j].content.indexOf(text) != -1){
                     res.push(myData[i].content[j]);
                 }
             }
         }
         return res;
     }

 // var myData = require("./data.json");
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
   // const {navigator} = this.props.navigator;
      if(!this.state.onSearch){
                return (

                  <View style={styles.container}>

                      <FlatList
                          data={myData}
                          getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
                              {length: 1000, offset: 60 * index, index}
                          )}
                          initialScrollIndex={1}

                          ListHeaderComponent={() => <TextInput style={styles.searchInput} value={this.state.text}
                                                                onChangeText={(text) => {
                                                                    var searchResult = getSearchResult(this.state.text);
                                                                    this.setState({text:text, onSearch:true, searchResult: searchResult});

                                                                    //this.setState({})
                                                                }}/>}
                          renderItem={({item}) => <MyHomeListItem chapterName={item.chapterName} item={item}
                                                                  chapterTitle={item.chapterTitle} navigation={navigate}/> }

                      />


                  </View>

                );
      }else{
          return(
              <View style={styles.container}>
                  <TextInput style={styles.searchInput} value={this.state.text}
                             onChangeText={(text) => {
                                 this.setState({text:text, onSearch:true});
                                 var searchResult = getSearchResult(this.state.text);
                                 this.setState({text:text, onSearch:true, searchResult: searchResult});
                                 //this.setState({})
                             }}/>
                  <FlatList
                      renderItem={({item})=><Text>{item.content}</Text>}

                  />
                  <Text> "search: " {this.state.text}</Text>
              </View>

              );
      }
  }
```

I define the `getSearchResult(text)` method in the same class of the render() function, but when triggered, the console give a error that :

```
 Can't find variable: getSearchResult
```

Not very familiar with how to do this, can some one help me to find out what I have done wrongly? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the class function with **this**. try with this.getSearchResult.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in the question description, not in the code

Comment: try with this.getSearchResult

Comment: Thanks, that works! Not very familiar with the scope of the function in javascript, you should change that as an answer and I am happy to accept that :D